# how to get rid of login on debian bookworm startup?

Tags: debian

i'm trying to set up auto login on debian 12 but i don't find how as I don't have anything in /etc/lightdm.

Does somebody have an idea ?

Thanks in advance !

Comment: better post in server fault or superuser